# Swift -Countdown Timer with Milliseconds stops at 0 but shows 1 Second left

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I have a countdown timer that shows milliseconds and a label that shows the time as it runs. When it stops at zero instead of it showing `00:00.0` it shows **00:01.0**

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong:

```
weak var videoTimer: Timer?
var minutes = 2
var seconds = 0
var milliseconds = 0

func startTimer() {

    videoTimer?.invalidate()

    videoTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] _ in
        self?.timerIsRunning()
    })
    RunLoop.current.add(videoTimer!, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.common)
}

func timerIsRunning() {

    let millisecStr = "\(milliseconds)"
    let secondsStr = seconds > 9 ? "\(seconds)" : "0\(seconds)"
    let minutesStr = minutes > 9 ? "\(minutes)" : "0\(minutes)"

    timerLabel.text = "\(minutesStr):\(secondsStr).\(millisecStr)"

    if seconds == 0 {

        if minutes != 0 {
            minutes -= 1
        }
    }

    if milliseconds == 0 {

        seconds -= 1
    }

    if seconds < 0 {

        seconds = 59
    }

    if minutes == 0 && seconds == 0 && milliseconds == 0 {

        print(minutes) // prints 0
        print(seconds) // prints 0
        print(milliseconds) // prints 0

        videoTimer?.invalidate()
    }

    milliseconds -= 1

    if milliseconds < 0 {

        milliseconds = 9
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your millisecond function above  .. `00:01.0` means 10 milliseconds remaining ...

```
weak var videoTimer: Timer?
var minutes = 2
var seconds = 0
var milliseconds = 0

func startTimer() {

    videoTimer?.invalidate()

    videoTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] _ in
        self?.timerIsRunning()
    })
    RunLoop.current.add(videoTimer!, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.common)
}

func timerIsRunning() {

    showTimer()

    if seconds == 0 {

        if minutes != 0 {
            minutes -= 1
        }
    }

    if milliseconds == 0 {

        seconds -= 1
    }

    if seconds < 0 {

        seconds = 59
    }
  milliseconds -= 1

    if milliseconds < 0 {

        milliseconds = 9
    }
    if minutes == 0 && seconds == 0 && milliseconds == 0 {

        print(minutes) // prints 0
        print(seconds) // prints 0
        print(milliseconds) // prints 0

        showTimer()

        videoTimer?.invalidate()
    }


}

func showTimer() {
 let millisecStr = "\(milliseconds)"
    let secondsStr = seconds > 9 ? "\(seconds)" : "0\(seconds)"
    let minutesStr = minutes > 9 ? "\(minutes)" : "0\(minutes)"

    timerLabel.text = "\(minutesStr):\(secondsStr).\(millisecStr)"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's because the value you assigned to millisecStr, secondsStr, minutesStr, timerLabel.text are not the latest value. You should assign them after calculating.

just try this.

```
weak var videoTimer: Timer?
var minutes = 2
var seconds = 0
var milliseconds = 0

func startTimer() {

    videoTimer?.invalidate()

    videoTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] _ in
        self?.timerIsRunning()
    })
    RunLoop.current.add(videoTimer!, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.common)
}

func timerIsRunning() {

    if seconds == 0 {

        if minutes != 0 {
            minutes -= 1
        }
    }

    if milliseconds == 0 {

        seconds -= 1
    }

    if seconds < 0 {

        seconds = 59
    }

    let millisecStr = "\(milliseconds)"
    let secondsStr = seconds > 9 ? "\(seconds)" : "0\(seconds)"
    let minutesStr = minutes > 9 ? "\(minutes)" : "0\(minutes)"

    timerLabel.text = "\(minutesStr):\(secondsStr).\(millisecStr)"

    if minutes == 0 && seconds == 0 && milliseconds == 0 {

        print(minutes) // prints 0
        print(seconds) // prints 0
        print(milliseconds) // prints 0

        videoTimer?.invalidate()
    }

    milliseconds -= 1

    if milliseconds < 0 {

        milliseconds = 9
    }
}
```